# Corrrect treatment of a limit approaching zero in complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

How to (correctly) evaluate this limit? $$\lim_{k\to0}\left(\frac{\mathrm{i}+k}{\mathrm{i}-k}\right)^{-\frac{\mathrm{i}}{k}}$$

Here $\mathrm{i}$ is the imaginary unit.

Mathematica gives $1/e^2$ (code `Limit[((I + k)/(I - k))^(-I/k), k -> 0]`).

Further, would anything change in the treatment if $k$ was complex and I approached the limit point $k=0$ from a general direction in the complex plane? I forgot how does one deal with this.

Comment: You Mathematica code doesn't match. Check the denominator.

Comment: @MrSlunk Popped up during the initial changes, corrected.

Comment: Question updated and a partial answer posted.

Answer (score 2):

Divide both numerator and denominator by $i^{-\frac ix}$, then write limit as
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{i+x}{i-x}\right)^{-\frac ix}&=\frac{\lim_{x\to0}(1-ix)^{-\frac ix}}{\lim_{x\to0}(1+ix)^{-\frac ix}}\\&=\frac{\lim_{x\to0}e^{-ix\left(-\frac ix\right)}}{\lim_{x\to0}e^{ix\left(-\frac ix\right)}}\\&=\frac{e^{-1}}{e^1}\\&=\frac1{e^2}\end{align}$$
This is solution without L'Hopital's rule. I used fact that
$$\lim_{x\to0}(1+x)^\frac1x=e$$
Therefore, $\left(1+f(x)\right)^\frac1{f(x)}\to e$ for any function $f(x)\to0$.

Answer (score 0):

The usual trick with exponential does it: $lim_{k->0}f(k)=e^{lim_{k->0}\ln(f(k)}$ and then l'Hôpital's rule gives $e^{-2}$.